# How do I prevent CopyCopter(client & server on Heroku) text from reverting to Default values?

Tags: heroku, content-management-system, copycopter

Occasionally text reverts to default values.  Particular in the mornings.

My guess, since both are running on Heroku, is that one or both apps are put to sleep on low volume days.

If I am guessing correctly, it seems likely, there is a best practices (and free) way to prevent the apps from going to sleep on Heroku? Perhaps frequent pinging (what do you use?), set some variable or a way to tell the apps to wake up an be available at some early time in the morning?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to keep a Heroku app from going to sleep, the simplest thing is to add a second dyno.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a serivce like http://www.pingdom.com/ to ping your app every so often and keep the dyno from going to sleep (I think up to once a minute for one app is free).

A second option is to set the timeout to a higher value.

```
#config/initializers/copycopter.rb

CopycopterClient.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = key_xxx
  config.host = site_xxx
  config.http_read_timeout = 120
  config.http_open_timeout = 120
end
```